# Render partial view overwriting the same page in Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, partial-views

I am having a grid records and a button at the top of the grid. Once a record is selected from the grid and button is clicked, I have to render a partial view with a form inside. I don't know how to render partial views from controller. Please find my folder structure below:

```
--views
  --partials
    --header
    --footer
    --main
    --form_page
--route
  --index
  --api
    --grid
```

`Header` and `footer` is default for all the pages. Initially `main` page will be rendered as partial view. I have to replace it with `form_page` after the button click. It is based on express js and handlebars.

Comment: what code you have tried till now ?

Comment: I have no idea of that. I just tried out `res.render` and `res.sendFile` methods to achieve this. My concept is how to navigate between partial views inside the main page. I am rendering like this `<header>{{> header }}</header>
  <div class="container-fluid body-content">
  {{{body}}}
   </div>
<footer>{{> footer }}</footer>`